# '/youtubei/v1/' at "www.googleapis.com", gives out a 405 error page

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**for some reason this url: https://www.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/ gives out this:
405. That’s an error.
The request method GET is inappropriate for the URL /youtubei/v1/. That’s all we know.
and i tried:
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/search?key=[api_key_goes_here]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/search?key=%5Bapi_key_goes_here%5D) and it won't work that way either and
i wonder why this give out a 405 error page?
the project im doing here is for innertube.
what im really tryin to accomplish is the innertube node class so the leanbacklite v3 can load the base url successfully**:

```
class com.google.youtube.tv.tree.innertube.InnerTubeNode extends com.google.youtube.tv.tree.ListNode
{
   static var URL_BASE = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/";
   function InnerTubeNode(title, loadNow)
   {
      super(title,this.makeUrl(),loadNow);
      this.setMenuCapturing(true);
   }
   function parse(src)
   {
   }
   function createChildren()
   {
   }
   function makeUrl()
   {
      var _loc2_ = com.google.youtube.tv.util.StringUtil.addParamsToRequest(com.google.youtube.tv.tree.innertube.InnerTubeNode.URL_BASE + this.service,["key=" + com.google.youtube.tv.app.Config.API_KEY,"alt=xml"]);
      return _loc2_;
   }
   function loadMore()
   {
      if(this.loadStarted)
      {
         return undefined;
      }
      this.loadStarted = true;
      this.setDataFetcher();
      this.fetcher.fetch(this.getURL());
   }
   function createDataFetcher()
   {
      if(this.loaded)
      {
         return undefined;
      }
      return new com.google.youtube.tv.data.InnerTubeDataFetcher();
   }
}
```

**the leanback lite v3 gives out a "YouTube is unavailable" message because this url base gives out a 405 error page for some reason that i dont know**

Comment: Your URL is incorrect, see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#http-request).

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior that you want to accomplish.

Comment: i have edited the post for a little more explanation